# Join query return duplicate data in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have run a join query based on client_id between directsales and clients table.
but when i print the query result it's show duplicated data.

here, is my code.

```
public function readirectsalereport(Request $request)
{
    $client_id=$request->client_id;
    $fromdate=$request->frmdate;
    $todate=$request->todate;

        $dsale=DB::table('directsales')
            ->join('clients','directsales.client_id','=','clients.id')
            ->select('clients.client_name','clients.addr')
            ->where('directsales.client_id','=',$client_id)
            ->get();

            return $dsale;

}
```

and it's show this result.

```
[{"client_name":"majed10","addr":"Uttara"},{"client_name":"majed10","addr":"Uttara"}]
```

Comment: INNER JOIN's can return duplicated records indeed. Laraval's function distinct() should help you out here.

Comment: leftJoin('clients', function($join) {

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use distinct method:

```
$dsale=DB::table('directsales')
            ->join('clients','directsales.client_id','=','clients.id')
            ->select('clients.client_name','clients.addr')
            ->where('directsales.client_id','=',$client_id)
            ->distinct()
            ->get();
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#selects

Comment: if, I want to add sum function in this query. how can i ??

Comment: You can add a raw query in it, but maybe it will not work with distinct. You can try with groupBy, it should fit the problem.

Comment: I appreciate this answer! The Laravel documentation inside the Database section has a single reference to distinct() in an example and no notes on it at all.

Comment: not working for me